# jQuery get keywords of background-position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the **left**, **right**, **center** from any element in javascript / jquery.

`$(div).css('background-position');`

This returns numbers like **0% 50% 100%**

There is any way to convert this into keywords?

Comment: what do you mean with "keywords"? which kind of keywords?

Comment: Convert to number and create the keywords yourself based on conditional ranges. Many values or units that are used to set css are not what browser uses when they return computed style

Comment: @quirimmo left, right, center = keywords

Comment: can you paste your background-position assignment?

Comment: @quirimmo what difference does that make? If the assignment value is text...browser converts to numeric values

Comment: you should use if else case and convert percentage to left/right/center as per your requirement... @Adrian

Comment: @charlietfl can't use numbers because I will broke everything, so the only solution can be something like this `if(pos[x] == 0%) else ...`?

Comment: just to see if there was some error in the CSS assignment, btw I think the conversion is the only road. 
First value is the left position, so 0% means left, 50% means center, 100% means right 
Second value is the top position, so 0% means top, 50% means center, 100% means bottom

Comment: Yes... that's exactly what I mean ... conditionals to check ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe instead of creating a plenty of if/else conditions, you can try an approach like the following:

```
const leftPositions = {
    '0%': 'left',
    '50%': 'center',
    '100%': 'right'
};
const topPositions = {
    '0%': 'top',
    '50%': 'center',
    '100%': 'bottom'
};

function getWordPositions(stringPosition) {
    let leftPosition = leftPositions[stringPosition.split(" ")[0]] || stringPosition.split(" ")[0];
    let topPosition = topPositions[stringPosition.split(" ")[1]] || topPosition.split(" ")[1];
    return leftPosition + ' ' + topPosition;
}

console.log($('div').css('background-position'));
console.log(getWordPositions($('div').css('background-position')));
```